# While publishing page we are getting this error in AEM :: failed to retrieve references for the selected page in aem

Tags: aem, aem-6, aem-63, adobe-exprience-manager

We have 3 pages checkout, review-order and order-confirmation page. When we quick publish checkout and review-order page, publishing is happening but when we are doing quick publish for order-confirmation page we are getting below error.

ERROR : failed to retrieve references for the selected page in aem

Note:

1. Quick publish is not working for order-confirmation page.
2. Using Manage publication we are able to publish order-confirmation page.

can some one help me to understand why this Quick publish is giving an error but Manage Publication is working fine.

1. I have removed all the component from the page and try to publish.
2. I have added jcr:lastModified and jcr:lasModifiedBy under jcr:content of order-confirmation page

Comment: There should be a stack trace in the error log explaining what went wrong. This interface is backed with any number of [Reference Provider](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/reference/ReferenceProvider.html) implementations, some of which may be custom ones. It's difficult to tell what exactly went wrong without seening the call stack.

Comment: You should not add jcr:lastModified and jcr:lasModifiedBy manually, they are created when you edit the page and replicate it via the AEM author interface.

Answer (score 0):

One More underline point is that If **cq:lastReplicationAction** is present, then **cq:lastReplicated** (date value) is must in 6.5 of any JCR node property of that page while publishing from author to live

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).